# Get cell highlight for specfic row & column in QTableWidget using Python pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am using Python and pyqt4. 
My QTableWidget allows multiple cell selections by the user.
For a single specific row & column cell in a QTableWidget, I need to read whether that cell has been highlighted by user selection or not highlighted.
What is the pyqt call to read a cell's selection/highlight value?

EDIT: I need to do it without a signal/slot call.  I simply have a QTableWidget and a row and column number and I need to get if that cell is selected or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`list-of-QTableWidgetItem QTableWidget.selectedItems (self)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems) to get selected item from user selection or highlighted. And handle signal [`void itemSelectionChanged ()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) to doing when item selection changed;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setRowCount(3)
        self.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Test 1'))
        self.setItem(0, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Test 2'))
        self.setItem(1, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Work 1'))
        self.setItem(1, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Work 2'))
        self.setItem(2, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Area 1'))
        self.setItem(2, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Area 2'))
        self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.itemSelectionChangedCallback)

    def itemSelectionChangedCallback (self):
        print '#' * 80
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.selectedItems():
            print currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget()
    myQCustomTableWidget.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

> EDIT: I need to do it without a signal/slot call. I simply have a
>   QTableWidget and a row and column number and I need to get if that
>   cell is selected or not.

In PyQt4 only have method [`bool QTableWidget.isItemSelected (self, QTableWidgetItem item)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#isItemSelected) available to used. If you want to use by index of row & column, You have to create new method your own. Use Use [`list-of-QTableWidgetItem QTableWidget.selectedItems (self)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#selectedItems) for check row and column is match;

```
class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    .
    .
    .

    def isItemSelectedByIndex (self, row, column):
        isSelection = False
        for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.selectedItems():
            if (row, column) == (currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column()):
                isSelection = True
                break
        return isSelection
```

Comment: I should have clarified... I need to do it without a signal/slot call.  I simply have a qtablewidget and a row and column number and I need to get if that cell is selected or not.

Comment: Your can get all selected item with `list-of-QTableWidgetItem QTableWidget.selectedItems (self)`. You can check it in here.